# Calling ISJSON multiple times in dynamic query gives weird error

Tags: json, sql-server

So I have a database table with a string field that should contain well-formed json.
I also have a dynamic query builder that will query the json, this is built at runtime so for each filter on the json I have the following sql

`ISJSON(Properties) > 0 AND JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$.aKey') = 'AValue)`

Because the query is dynamic I can end up with a query that looks like this

```
SELECT Id, Properties 
FROM [RecommendTest].[dbo].[TRecommendation2]
WHERE 
       (ISJSON(Properties) > 0 AND JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$._imps') = 'true')
    OR (ISJSON(Properties) > 0 AND JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$._imps') = 'false')
```

In SSMS this returns the right results but also throws up a message if I have a row in the db that contains invalid json in the Properties field.
Message is this

Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'o' is found at position 1.

This is a problem because I'm actually using this in EFCore and an exception is being thrown.

Interestingly if I do this (logically the same)

```
SELECT Id, Properties 
FROM [RecommendTest].[dbo].[TRecommendation2]
WHERE 
       ISJSON(Properties) > 0 
       AND ( JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$._imps') = 'true'
       OR JSON_VALUE(Properties, '$._imps') = 'false' )
```

I get the same results but I don't get the message

I'm guessing this is query optimizer weirdness... any ideas?

Comment: The problem you're facing is that there's nothing stopping  the data engine resolving the clause with `JSON_VALUE` in it *before* it resolves the `ISJSON` one. As a result if the JSON is invalid and the `JSON_VALUE` is resolved first, you get an error. Ideally, why not stop invalid JSON being inserted into the database in the first place? You could validate the value in both the application and database layer (with a `CONSTRAINT`) if you really wanted. Then you don't have to worry about checking if it's valid or not in the `WHERE`, as it'll always be valid.

Comment: You need to force the optimizer to evaluate the `isjson` first, you could try a subquery or CTE, possibly with a rowgoal or evaluating it using an `apply`

Comment: Consider a CROSS APPLY.   You can stack and reference the calculated values as needed via the given alias.

Comment: `JSON_VALUE(case when isjson(Properties)=1 then Properties end, '$._imps') in ('true', 'false')`